# Unable to download PDF file using Chrome WebDriver with kiosk-printing option in Java Selenium when run on Jenkins

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, pdf, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Java Selenium and WebDriver to navigate to a website and perform various actions. One of those actions is printing a PDF of the current page using Chrome WebDriver with the kiosk-printing option to bypass the Chrome print dialog window. There is a specific print button on the site that is being clicked. However, I am having trouble downloading the PDF file from the website when the automation is run on Jenkins. When the automation is run locally, the code works as expected and downloads the file without displaying the print dialog. For reference, I am developing on a Mac and the Jenkins server is run off of a windows machine. My company has been writing automations in this way for over a year and we have never experienced an issue with file downloads in the past. We are using Chrome as the browser for automation.

I have tried multiple different chrome driver settings:

```
prefs.put("download.behavior", "allow");
prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", false);
prefs.put("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", "true"); 
prefs.put("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/pdf");
prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
prefs.put("plugins.plugins_disabled","Chrome PDF Viewer");
prefs.put("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", true);
            
chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--download.default_directory=/random/path/for/online/question");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--download.file_types=pdf");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--kiosk-printing");
```

I have had success automating the chrome print dialog, but it always results in an operating system dialog opening asking where the file should be saved. I have attempted to use the Robot class to send keys to that dialog, but the Robot does not have the os dialog within its immediate context, so it sends all keystrokes to the Desktop rather than the dialog.

Again, this issue only occurs when the automation is run on Jenkins rather than my local machine. Jenkins does however have access to the destination directory and all parent directories as we are using the same automation to create and manipulate files in the destination.

Comment: This is my first question posted to stack overflow, so please be kind!

Comment: Take a look at the Chrome section of [How to Print Page as PDF with Selenium 4](https://saucelabs.com/resources/blog/print-page-pdf). Ignore the `sauceOptions` stuff. I have use this same approach using [Chrome DevTools Java Client](https://github.com/kklisura/chrome-devtools-java-client) instead of Selenium.

Comment: We ended up having to scrape the html off the webpage and use it to generate a pdf ourselves. @pfurbacher thank you for your input!